# Javascript: How to use same button for different text input?

Tags: javascript, textinput

Suppose I have 2 input elements with only 1 button. I want the button to do a function for one input element at a time according to which one is currently being focused but I don't know how to capture focusing status of each element.

Please consider this example:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var id_box = document.createElement('input');
id_box.id = 'id_box';
id_box.type = 'text';
div.appendChild(id_box);

var weight_box = document.createElement('input');
weight_box.id = 'weight_box';
weight_box.type = 'text';
div.appendChild(weight_box);

function showLetter() {
    if (id_box is being focused){
        document.getElementById('id_box').value = 'ABC';
    }
    if (weight_box is being focused){
        document.getElementById('weight_box').value = 'ABC';
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="showLetter()">ABC</button>
</body>
```

Any idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: I assume that in the second case you mean `getElementById("weight_box")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an input has focus and if the user then clicks a button the input will lose focus instantly so you cannot detect which input has focus in the way you want.

You could create a variable that stores the "current" input by attaching an event handler to each input for the `onFocus` event.

**Demo on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P58sx/1/**

```
var current_input;

function showLetter() {
  current_input.value = 'ABC';
}

function setCurrentInput() {
  console.log(this);
  current_input = this;
}

var id_box = document.createElement('input');
id_box.id = 'id_box';
id_box.type = 'text';
id_box.addEventListener("focus", setCurrentInput);
div.appendChild(id_box);

var weight_box = document.createElement('input');
weight_box.id = 'weight_box';
weight_box.type = 'text';
weight_box.addEventListener("focus", setCurrentInput);
div.appendChild(weight_box);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I'm guessing it's because I'm using IE (not by choice...)  It's the correct concept though.

Comment: I just found that it works only with Chrome but not Firefox. Is there another way to make it works with Firefox or other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The minute you click the button, the textfield loses focus anyway.  Try trapping the OnFocus method for each text box and set a variable to the instance of the textfield.  This way you have the latest text field and you don't need your if statement.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying the `onFocus` event handler.

Comment: In what way would you recommend it?

Answer (score 0):

One trick would be to declare a variable and setting it in `onFocus` event of each field. Then in the button code you can check what was the last field that was focused before the click on the button.